# How to look for a string in file path, whithin For loop

Tags: batch-file

I need to copy some files in a certain directory to another loction, but only files that contains some string within their full path.

I tried:

```
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set source=c:\temp\*.*
set dest=c:\temp\dest\

For %%A in ("%source%") do (
   if not x%filename:SOMESTRING=%==x%%A copy %%A %dest%
)
```

I get this message: =A was unexpected at this time.

Comment: What's the value of `%filename%`?

Comment: Try something like `echo %%A^|find /i "your string to find" ^>nul && copy "%%~A" "%dest%"`

Comment: I'm not understanding why you're not using `C:\temp\*your string to find*` as the string value for `%source%`, for example `Set "source=C:\temp\*your string to find*"`.